# React Native: uri image display black block, after some moment app crash

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to display an image from a URL. In the emulator, the image displays perfectly. When I run this on the device it displays a black block and after some moment the app crashes without any error.

If I remove *borderRadius, borderColor, borderWidth* property from *Image style* it works perfectly. But I need the circular shape.

I tried to native-base *Thumbnail* instead of *Image* but the problem persists. Then I tried to make a circular shape using *View* with *overflow:hidden* property but here the image edge not smooth. How can I solve this?

Black Block image in the device:
[image: Screenshot: Black Block image in the device]
My code:
[image: Screenshot: My code]

Comment: app is running in debug mode?

Comment: Are you able to use debug it on your device using LogCat to see the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: @Asad Yes, I have run this debug mode.

Comment: @Dan I have try to trace crash in adb LogCat. There is no error. The source link of images are opening in browser successfully. I don't know how to solve this issue. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

*The problem is solved.
The main problem was Google Cloud Storage where I stored the pictures.

Having trouble using various features of Google Cloud Platform from my country.

The black blocks we see here are basically loading from cache memory. So there are showing black block in circular shape. Because, images are saved in cache memory with square shape.

I have tried in VPN and everything is ok.
Thank you.